# My static instance function of my class does not work as I expected

Tags: c++, class, instance

I wrote a class like this:

```
class memUsage {
    public:
     memUsage();
     void addByte(int amount);
     int   used_byte(){return total_byte;}
     static memUsage* Instance(){return new memUsage();}   

private:
   int total_byte;
};

memUsage::memusage()
{
   total_byte = 0;
}

memUsage::addByte(int amount)
{
 total_byte +=amount;
}
```

Then I just call it with:

```
memUsage::Instance()->addByte(512);
memUsage::Instance()->addByte(512);
```

this function always return 0:

```
int test  = memUsage::Instance()->used_byte();
```

I copied the instance design from somewhere I don't remember,so I don't know if this is the right way to do it,or what do I need to change?

Comment: It's called a "singleton". That term should help you find reasonably correct implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Instance` function creates a new instance every time it is called, so

```
memUsage::Instance()->addByte(512);
memUsage::Instance()->addByte(512);
```

calls `addByte` on two different object instances.

And as `Instance` also creates a new object every time it's called, but you never free that object, you have a memory leak as well.

---

A singleton "get instance" function typically looks like

```
static memUsage* Instance()
{
    static memUsage instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

Comment: ... and the `used_byte()` query is called on *yet another* instance.